# Ag-grid set autoheight in Master/Detail component

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, vuejs2, ag-grid

Suppose we need to set the autoheight of an ag-grid component it can be done easily with setting `gridOptions` to `domLayout="autoHeight"`. This works in a single component, but for master-detail (parent/children) component that heights can be expanded, this doesn't work.

Same issue :
https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/205

I need to tweak deep into its css but still can't make it work,

[image]

Style reference: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-styling/

Ag grid DOM Layout: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-width-and-height/#gsc.tab=0

Example to reproduce :
https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-vue-example (see on Master/Detail)

**It's either tweaking the gridOptions `getRowheight` or its embedded css**

for the related css :

```
.ag-root {
/* set to relative, so absolute popups appear relative to this */
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
/* was getting some 'should be there' scrolls, this sorts it out */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ag-body {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/dist/styles/ag-grid.css

and a plunker inside:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/#gsc.tab=0

Another clue from the author: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-height/index.php#gsc.tab=0

> Height for Pinned Rows Row height for pinned rows works exactly as per
>   normal rows with one difference - it is not possible to dynamically
>   change the height once set. However, this is easily got around by just
>   setting the pinned row data again which resets the row heights.
>   Setting the data again is not a problem for pinned rows as it doesn't
>   impact scroll position, filtering, sorting or group open/closed> positions as it would with normal rows if the data was reset.

Answer (score 7):

You can dynamically calculate row height.

```
getRowHeight: function (params) {
    if (params.node && params.node.detail) {
        var offset = 80;
        var allDetailRowHeight = params.data.callRecords.length * 28;
        return allDetailRowHeight + offset;
    } else {
        // otherwise return fixed master row height
        return 60;
    }
}
```

You can find this [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/#example-dynamic-detail-row-height) in official documentation of ag-grid.

Comment: they refer to this approach as dynamic, I don't get how this is dynamic we are able to dynamically set the height of the detail grid, but instead rows are being statically assigned heights; ~28 is case of detail grid and 60 in case of master grid. I am looking for a more dynamic way i.e. rows with variable heights and avoiding vertical scroll for detail grids altogether. I use autoHeight, which works for normal grids but not for master detail. Are you aware of any more concrete workaround? I do have an open [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54269443/6181692) if you want details,

Comment: (A year later..) Yup, I'm wondering the same thing.... how to get child grids to only take up as much height as is needed, and how to add an *alternative* styling to them. You would think that this would be easier by now.....

Answer (score 2):

For anyone finding this question in late 2021 and beyond, there's now the detailRowAutoHeight property in the gridOptions which will achieve the results desired by the asker.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/master-detail-height/#auto-height

```
const gridOptions = {
    // dynamically set row height for all detail grids
    detailRowAutoHeight: true,

    // other grid options ...
}
```

Comment: this is causing slow collapse of he row for me.

Comment: I think I experienced this as well and it turned out I was setting some other height property elsewhere, but that's going back about 9 months so can't remember the details.

Comment: niceeeeeeeeeeee